# Summing one-sided limits?

Tags: limits, combinations

So I'm trying to find $$\lim_{x \to 0} ((e^x)/(cos(x)-cosh(x)) = (\lim_{x \to 0}(e^x))/(\lim_{x \to 0} cos(x) - \lim_{x \to 0} cosh(x)) = 1/((1^-)-(1^+))$$

The problem is I don't know if $(1^-)-(1^+)$ is $(0^+)$ or $(0^-)$ or even just $0$ nor can I find any general rules for combinations of one sided limits.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Yo need $(1^-)-(1^+)=0^-$. Moreover note that in your case the denominator is negative since $\cos x\leq 1<\cosh x$  for $|x|>0$.

Comment: $\cosh(x) \ge \cos(x)$ for all $x$ $($with equality iff $x=0)$ so $ \cos(x) - \cosh(x) < 0$ $($except at $x=0)$ Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I was hoping more for a general rule on adding one sided limits but your answers make sense so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

this limit doesn't exist, since it is of the form $$\frac{1}{0}$$ and we get $$-\infty$$